# What are the Pros and Cons of having one-to-many bi-direcional relationships in Entity Framework (4.1)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on a new project that makes use of Entity Framework. I was in love with relationship inverses, having navigation properties on both types would make my life really easier.
Problem is: our project manager thinks that using this facility may lead to mistakes and thus is advising us not to use it.

Let's say we have Category and Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

He says that one can, by mistake, set productZ.Category to categoryX and then do a categoryY.Products.Add(productZ), for example. Then what relationship will be persisted when we save the context? The last one? Ok, what if the first one was the correct category? And that this kind of error is hard to debug (which I agree).

I don't think this scenario can happen but I really respect his opinion, he's way more experienced than me, but I really want to convince him to let us have bidirectional navigation properties and the only argument I have is: if everyone is doing it then it cannot be this bad. :)

Can you guys help me with some more solid arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> one can by mistake ...

One can also write unit test to validate that code sets expected relations. You can always make mistake and removing navigation property is not a solution to avoid the problem. The solution is to validate that your code does what is expected = testing and code coverage.

What you ask is more about designing your classes - not about mistakes. Is it meaningful to have navigation properties on both sides? Are you adding product to category or assigning category to product? Do you need to offer both ways? Can product exists without category? Are you handling products and categories separately or are they aggregate? Based on answers to these questions you can sometimes find that navigation property on one side of relation is not necessary.

Comment: When adding a new product we mostly would preffer to simply assign the category to the product and then insert it. Sometimes we will work with a product and it's category, but there's also the need to access all products from a single category (or even from all categories). See my point?

Comment: Products from single category or all categories can be accessed through separate query over products.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with your project manager, especially when reading "he's way more experienced than me", as it suggests at least some of the team is a bit green (yourself?) and likely to make the type of mistakes he mentions. The problem you are describing is much like storing a value in multiple databases (sometimes a necessary evil) and not setting one of the databases as the master.

While a bi-directional "relationship" might make things a bit easier, it is not so much easier that I would add the risk of messing up the data through a simple coding mistake. The fact you can navigate  without adding the bi-directional support (perhaps not with as simple a statement, but it can be done), I would have to have strong arguments for using them.

Comment: Well, being less experienced is not the same as being inexperienced. That said, yes, I'm afraid he does not have enough confidence on the team to let this potential troublemaker open.

Comment: I did not mean inexperienced, so I hope it did not come across that way. But handing a method like this to a less experienced team is like handing a gun to an older child. Most likely, nothing bad will happen, but the potential is greater. With code that can be completely incapsulated, you reduce the risk, but when you are talking your domain model, you can't completely encapsulate to protect the developers from themselves. I would find the risk too great unless someone could convince me why it was needed.

Comment: The question that hammers my mind is 'If it's this dangerous then why in the world every single EF example does implement it and none of them alerts for this kind of problem?'. I think one should be really harebrained to make this kind of mistake.

Comment: Much of the Microsoft stuff is designed to make things simpler and lower the bar to get up and running. It is not designed to stop people from making mistakes. As for why the samples are like that, I am not certain. But, I also don't understand why LINQ to SQL statements sit in ASP.NET MVC samples either, as it tightly couples MVC to the data access. Ouch!